# unwanted stimulus time offset in hyperlynx si

Tags: simulation, signal-integrity, hyperlynx

I am using hyperlynx-si to simulate the eye-diagram of a serial link in my design. 
[image]
I've took a 0.66 Gbps random pattern as the stimulus, but as can be seen in the picture, there is an unwanted 300ps offset in the signal just at the driver's output pin, which caused the eye-mask not to fit in the center of the bit. How can I avoid this time offset? or it is a normal case?
thanks in advnace.
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of R4?  Try removing it.

Comment: Tried it out! no difference yet! :(

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain the solution to your problem lies in the time offset box in the ‘Eye Mask,’ tab of the dialog box you showed in your snapshot.

In your dialog box, if you click the tab that says 'Eye Mask,' do you see the offset there?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/202354)

Comment: It was intended to answer the question. I am pretty sure the dialog box I mentioned is where his problem lies and will be the solution for avoiding the time offset like he asked. I will add clarification.

Comment: @scuba Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, it is possible to adjust the eye mask manually or by setting the Offset field. But I am afraid what is the causing this issue?